# mongodb and cassandra pros/cons for a multidatacenter system

Tags: mongodb, cassandra

I need information, pros/cons about multidatacenter replication in mongodb replica sets vs cassandra for a 3 node (one of them is in another datacenter) setup.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/deploying-cassandra-across-multiple-data-centers

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB has no master-master replication which is usually desirable for replication across data center - at least when you want to deal with writes in each data-center. With replica sets in MongoDb you have only one master for the writes. If reading from the secondaries in one data-center is "good enough" then MongoDB with replica-sets might be an option but if master-master replication is a requirement.